# why this flexDirection with justifyContent has same view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some React Native code that looks like this:

```
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
      <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
    </View>
```

but the two Views look the same, like in this image:

[image: view on virtual device]

Even though in the above one `justifyContent` is set to `space-between`, it shows as if it was set to `center`.

Comment: I think the space-between view has limited width.
See https://jsbin.com/yitusakelo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: What component are the two Views within?

Comment: ok thanks, the two View within a parent View with `alignItems: 'center'`. I've solved after deleted their parent view's style attribute. @PedroCastilho , @paibarmboo